How to find all the unique constructions of simple Venn diagrams with a small number of sets?
so I was doing some research regarding Venn diagrams and I stumbled on this paper
In it, it states that:
“It is not hard to verify that there is a unique type of Venn diagram with two curves, one type of simple Venn diagram with three curves, and just two types of simple diagram with four curves.”
It does not further elaborate on how these claims can be verified. I was wondering if someone can walk me through how can these claims be proven. I want to say it relates to the dual graphs of the Venn diagrams, but I’m not sure how to go from here.
Thank you for helping in advance.

Indeed, it is not that clear... Besides, here is a connected issue.

and also this one.
